# How to write ASCII in the OutputStream

Tags: java

**According to the Datamax Documentation:**

```
<CR> is used to identify the line termination character. Other strings placed
between < > in this manual represent the character of the same ASCII name, and
are single-byte hexadecimal values (e.g., <STX>, <CR>, and <0x0D> equal 02, 0D,
and 0D, respectively).
```

I was trying to write the code < CR> in the Printer OutputStream but I dont know how? I tried the following code:

```
outputStream.write("<CR>");
```

But it didnt worked. How do I write ASCII and Hexadecimal in the outputstream?

Comment: "it didnt worked" *never* makes for a good question. What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/

`<CR>` is hex `D`, decimal `13`, octal `015`.

In a Java string literal, this can be escaped in 3 ways:

- `\r` [Carriage Return](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6)
- `\u000d` [Unicode Escape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3)
- `\015` [Octal Escape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6)

Looking at that ASCII table again, you can also see that `<STX>` is hex `2`, decimal `2`, octal `2`, which in Java is either `\002` or `\u0002`. There is no letter version of `<STX>`, like the `\r` for `<CR>`.

Note: Octal form can be written in 1-, 2-, or 3-digit variants, e.g. `\2`, `\02`, `\002`, but 3-digit version is best. Actually, the JLS says:

> Octal escapes are provided for compatibility with C, but can express only Unicode values `\u0000` through `\u00FF`, so Unicode escapes are usually preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `<CR>` means "carriage-return", i.e. `"\r"`. However, if you've got an `OutputStream` and you want to write text to it, I would suggest wrapping it in an `OutputStreamWriter`, specifying the appropriate encoding. You can then use text-oriented calls appropriately.

For other values, you can use `\uxxxx`, e.g. `\u0002` for STX.

Comment: Can you give me an example oh how to do it?

Comment: How did you came up with \u0002 for STX?

Comment: @TheWell: Based on the documentation you showed, wanting character 02. And you should try it for yourself - OutputStreamWriter is easy to use.